# MVC-3 and Dynamic - @Html.Label(View.X) not Rendering

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using MVC-3, Razor:

-- MyController --

```
public ActionResult Index(String message) // where message = "hello"
{
      ViewModel.Test1 = "This is a test";
      ViewModel.Test2 = "This is another test. " + message;
}
```

-- Index.cshtml --

```
@Html.Label((string)View.Test1)
<br />
@Html.Label((string)View.Test2)
```

Why will it only render out the following?

```
<label for="This is a test">This is a test</label>
<br />
```

It's been driving me absolutely crazy over the past few days and seems to make no sense.  There has to be a reason for it.

I can debug this and step through thew view.  In the view, I watch as this line is processed and the value of View.Test2 is "This is another test. hello".

I have cases where I am doing the following and it works fine.
(ex)

```
ViewModel.Something = this.readDataService.GetSomething();
```

What's the difference?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using a pre-RC2 version of ASP.NET MVC 3.  `ViewModel` was changed to `ViewBag` in RC 2 (see the [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx) by Scott Guthrie).

> With earlier previews of ASP.NET MVC 3 we exposed this API using a dynamic property called “ViewModel” on the Controller base class, and with a dynamic property called “View” within view templates.  A lot of people found the fact that there were two different names confusing, and several also said that using the name ViewModel was confusing in this context – since often you create strongly-typed ViewModel classes in ASP.NET MVC, and they do not use this API.
>
> With RC2 we are exposing a dynamic property that has the same name – ViewBag – within both Controllers and Views.

And it does look like you are trying to use `ViewModel` as the strongly typed model for your view.  Instead, create a class to use as your model and then use `@Html.LabelFor`:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

in the controller:

```
PersonModel model = new PersonModel { Name = "John" };
return View(model);
```

in the view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name): @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

which renders:

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>: <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="John" />
```

HTH

Comment: adrift, thank you for your response.  Thanks for the prompting to get my application moved over to the most current MVC.  You're right, I should be using a model in all these views as a rule of thumb.  I will go this route and save the headache of the ViewBag. (BTW, I tested my app after migrating to the newer MVC, and it still has the same problem.  Time for a model!)  Thanks again for the response!